# AWS Lambda Support - Autoscaling

Tags: aws-lambda

What is the current QPS does AWS Lambda supports and does it autoscale based on incoming messages traffic? Say, my incoming traffic increases, will it autoscale by itself. Does it maintain a single server or multiple server at its side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AWS account will have a max concurrent Lambda invocation limit of 1000. You can request that AWS increase that limit on your account. The AWS Lambda limits are listed [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html).

Since AWS Lambda is a "serverless" technology you don't really need to think about or even care how many servers are running your Lambda function. Your Lambda function will automatically be deployed on as many servers as needed (up to your account limit) in order to handle the amount of requests it is getting.